# Is the set of two-qubit absolutely separable states convex?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, mathematics, density-matrix

*[Companion question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376200/is-the-set-of-two-qubit-absolutely-separable-states-convex-and-if-so-what-are) on MathOverflow*

Let us order the four nonnegative eigenvalues, summing to 1, of a two-qubit density matrix ($\rho$) as
\begin{equation}
1 \geq x \geq y \geq z \geq (1-x-y-z) \geq 0.
\end{equation}
The set ($S$) of absolutely separable states (those that can not be "entangled" by global unitary transformations) is defined by the additional inequality (eq. (1) in [Halder](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.13145))
\begin{equation}
x - z \leq 2 \sqrt{y (1-x-y-z)}.
\end{equation}

Is the set $S$, that is,
\begin{equation}
1 \geq x \geq y \geq z \geq (1-x-y-z) \geq 0 \land x - z \leq 2 \sqrt{y (1-x-y-z)}, 
\end{equation}
convex?

If so, I would like to seek to determine the John ellipsoids [JohnEllipoids](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral) containing and contained within $S$  and see if they are simply the same as the circumscribed ($\mbox{Tr}(\rho^2) \leq \frac{3}{8}$) and inscribed ($\mbox{Tr}(\rho^2) \leq \frac{1}{3}$) sets, respectively [Adhikari](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.00891)  .

These two sets are determined by the constraints
\begin{equation}
1 \geq x \geq y \geq z \geq (1-x-y-z) \geq 0 \land x^2 +y^2 +z^2 +(1-x-y-z)^2 \leq \frac{3}{8}.
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
1 \geq x \geq y \geq z \geq (1-x-y-z) \geq 0 \land x^2 +y^2 +z^2 +(1-x-y-z)^2 \leq \frac{1}{3}.
\end{equation}
(The latter set corresponds to the separable "maximal ball" inscribed in the set of two-qubit states (sec. 16.7 [GeometryQuantumStates](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Karol_Zyczkowski/publication/325707595_Geometry_of_quantum_states_An_introduction_to_quantum_entanglement/links/5e6ab206299bf12e23c03ea7/Geometry-of-quantum-states-An-introduction-to-quantum-entanglement.pdf)).

Further, I am interested in the Hilbert-Schmidt probabilities (relative volumes) [Hilbert-Schmidt](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/36/39/310/meta?casa_token=fwoPejONTqAAAAAA:lLOen_ZF-qPZxA0BpVDC03MA6-Cy2zHRHJFUssRFxYN_G8sHHllthiDt_XTVVUMDpbr4AHxSmc82Up0WpWk) of these various sets. These probabilities are obtained by integrating over these sets the expression
\begin{equation}
9081072000 \left(\lambda _1-\lambda _2\right){}^2 \left(\lambda _1-\lambda _3\right){}^2 \left(\lambda
   _2-\lambda _3\right){}^2 \left(2 \lambda _1+\lambda _2+\lambda _3-1\right){}^2 \left(\lambda _1+2
   \lambda _2+\lambda _3-1\right){}^2 \left(\lambda _1+\lambda _2+2 \lambda _3-1\right){}^2,
\end{equation}
where the four eigenvalues are indicated. (This integrates to 1, when only the eigenvalue-ordering constraint--given at the very outset--is imposed.)

In the answer to [4-ball](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234086/find-the-probability-relative-volume-of-a-certain-4-ball-with-respect-to-hilbe), we report formulas for the Hilbert-Schmidt probabilities (relative volumes) of these inscribed and circumscribed sets, that is,
\begin{equation}
\frac{35 \pi }{23328 \sqrt{3}} \approx 0.00272132
\end{equation}
and the considerably larger
\begin{equation}
\frac{35 \sqrt{\frac{1}{3} \left(2692167889921345-919847607929856 \sqrt{6}\right)} \pi}{27518828544} \approx 0.0483353.
\end{equation}
(We also have given an exact--but still quite cumbersome--formula [$\approx 0.00484591$] for $\mbox{Tr}(\rho^2) \leq \frac{17}{50}$.)

Further, in the answers to [AbsSepVol1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral) and [AbsSep2](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13749/give-an-explicit-derivation-of-the-exact-formula-for-the-two-qubit-absolute-sepa) ,
the formula for the Hilbert-Schmidt volume (confirming and rexpressing the one given in
[2009paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0393044008001381#bb16))
\begin{equation}
\frac{29902415923}{497664}-\frac{50274109}{512 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{3072529845 \pi }{32768
   \sqrt{2}}+\frac{1024176615 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{4096 \sqrt{2}} \approx 0.00365826
\end{equation}
of the intermediate absolutely separable set $S$ has been given.

As to the total (absolute and non-absolute) separability probability of the 15-dimensional convex set of two-qubit density matrices, compelling evidence of various kinds--though yet no formalized proof--indicate that its value is the considerably larger
$\frac{8}{33} \approx 0.242424$ [MasterLovasAndai](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11128-018-1854-5) . (One can also enquire as to the John ellipsoids for this [known-to-be] convex set [JohnEllipsoid2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369287/what-are-the-john-ellipsoids-for-a-pair-of-9-and-15-dimensional-convex-sets-o).)

Here is a joint plot of the three sets of central interest here.

[ThreeSetPlot](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/paulslater/Published/ThreeSetPlot)

Comment: It's written that $S$ is convex and compact in your first reference. The follow up reference is https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.89.052304

Comment: Thanks, Danylo Y!  I see that the convexity assertion is in the abstract of the follow up reference.

Comment: Nathaniel Johnston has given a quite thoughtful answer to the companion question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376200/is-the-set-of-two-qubit-absolutely-separable-states-convex-and-if-so-what-are He distinguishes between the ordered spectra of the absolutely separable states (the focus of my interest) and the (higher-dimensional) absolutely separable states (to which the Danylo comment pertains).

Comment: Mark S--the comment above yours references the "companion question". The MO question had the additional "(by definition, $4 \times 4$, Hermitian, nonnegative definite, trace one) "two-qubit density matrix"" intended for non-quantum-oriented folk.